YOLO detection don't detect static object
I have trained a YOLO detector and am now testing it to see how it works. I noticed that the detection stops when objects stop on the ground, while in motion they are detected. I have trained the detector as you can see below:
    model = YOLO(model_path)
    results_m = model.train(data= ROOT_DIR_YOLO + "data.yaml", single_cls=False, imgsz=640, epochs = 25)

Here are 2 examples... as you can see while the object is in movement it is detected, onece it no longer move, it is not detected anymore
detected
no more detected

Add more examples of the not-detected objects to your dataset and re-train.
